# Specify a Composite Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a Foreign Key out of two values in two different tables, some pointers would be appreciated!

Below is the code I am using for this :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeUnsetZone](
    [EmployeeID] [char](2) NULL,
    [ZoneOfficeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ZoneID] [char](4) NULL
    CONSTRAINT EmployeeUnsetZone_EmployeeFK FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeID],[ZoneID])
    REFERENCES [Employee]([ID]), [ZoneByOffice]([ID])
)
```

Comment: Why are the two columns needing foreign keys nullable?  Why is there no primary key defined for the table?  What are the business rules for the table?

Comment: This table is for storing an employee's rights to 'Unset' a particular 'Zone'. Don't know why those columns are nullable, must be a brain fart, but I've made them NOT NULL now.

I don't think I need a primary key for a table of rules like this, even if a duplicate snuck in there, no damage would be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeUnsetZone](
  [EmployeeID] [char](2) NULL,
  [ZoneOfficeID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [ZoneID] [char](4) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ([EmployeeID], [ZoneID]),
  CONSTRAINT fk_employeeid FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeID]) REFERENCES [Employee]([ID]),
  CONSTRAINT fk_zoneid FOREIGN KEY([ZoneID]) REFERENCES [ZoneByOffice]([ID])
)
```

The primary key will stop duplicates, and also setup the clustered key for the two columns to make searching against better.